# Stop component moving while hidding the component using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I need to prevent a component moving while hiding it using jquery.

In the jsfiddle, we can able to see Shape label is moving its position.

How can I stop this component from moving?

JsFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/g5j4P/

Please refer below code :

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('button.Down').click(function() { 
            $('.colorList').slideDown('fast'); 
            $('button.Down').hide(); 
        });
        $('button.Up').click(function() { 
            $('.colorList').slideUp('fast');
            $('button.Down').show();  
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<label>Color:</label>
<div class="colorContainer">
    <button type="button" id="Down" class="Down" style="margin-left: 30px;"> Down </button>
    <fieldset class="colorList" style="background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF; display:none; position: absolute; float:right; margin-left: 30px;">
         <span>Blue</span><br/>
         <span>White<br/></span>
         <span>Red<br/></span>
         <span>Orange<br/></span>
         <span>Green<br/></span>
         <span><button type="button" id="Up" class="Up"> UP </button></span>
    </fieldset>
</div>
<br>
<label>Shape:</label>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is really a general html question and not properly defined.  Nice that you have a fiddle, but what component is moving that you don't want to move?  If you don't want further components to move in your html, don't remove elements above them or use absolute sizes or positions.  I don't think this question as stated could help anyone else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not hide the button, instead use below css to hide the button below drop down.

**CSS**

```
.colorContainer{position:relative;}
.colorList{position:absolute; top:0; left:0;}
.opacity{opacity:0;}
```

**JS Code**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('button.Down').click(function() { 
        $('.colorList').slideDown('fast'); 
        $('button.Down').addClass('opacity'); 
    });
    $('button.Up').click(function() { 
        $('.colorList').slideUp('fast');
        $('button.Down').removeClass('opacity');  
    });
 });
```

[**Updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/g5j4P/5/)

Comment: Thanks for solving the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You could wrap the `button` in a `div` so that the label won't move when it is being hidden initially before sliding down.

```
<div id="dropdownContainer">
   <button type="button" id="Down" class="Down" style="margin-left: 30px;">Down</button>
</div>
```

And then giving a fixed `height` to that `div`.

```
#dropdownContainer {
    height: 15px;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/g5j4P/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `show()` and `hide()` use css `visibility` property. it will retain the space. see thisː http://jsfiddle.net/ravimallya/g5j4P/3/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('button.Down').click(function() { 
            $('.colorList').slideDown('fast'); 
            $('button.Down').css('visibility', 'hidden'); 
        });
        $('button.Up').click(function() { 
            $('.colorList').slideUp('fast');
            $('button.Down').css('visibility', 'visible');  
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('button.Down').click(function() { 
            $('.colorList').slideDown('fast'); 
            $('button.Down').css('visibility',' hidden'); 
        });
        $('button.Up').click(function() { 
            $('.colorList').slideUp('fast');
            $('button.Down').css('visibility', 'visible');  
        });
    });
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g5j4P/4/)

The problem occurred since you were using the `display` CSS property use `visibility` instead.

Comment: @Ravimallya i didnt see i was just updating the answer

Comment: No worries. Let it to be as it is :)